# Is there any way to use Regular expression in c#?

Tags: c#

I am having a situation here... I have a value like this in a variable like this

```
var getfile ="C:\Users\rohithkk\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\jstree3\jstree3\UploadedFiles\30102014214816202_JST.ods"
```

Here i want to get the value like this "30102014214816202_JST.ods" is there any way to do it in c#?

Thanks

Comment: No regex needed here. Just research effort.

Comment: Funny. They all r coming with different methods for this. He asked for a regex-solution didnt he? http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-match

Comment: @C4ud3x: Often the solution someone *asks* for isn't the most appropriate one for the situation. (Example: just a little while ago, someone asked how to escape quotes in values in MySQL. The best solution is not to escape them at all, but to use parameterized SQL.)

Comment: @C4ud3x - [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @Sayse: Interesting. I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is a way.

```
Path.GetFileName()
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/system.io.path.getfilename(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I asked this. because I am a beginner. Sry...